# Distance Between Points and Sets

Tags: real-analysis

You are given two sets $A, B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

Show that $\{ x \mid d(x, A) < d(x, B) \}$ is open.

Comment: Show that $x \mapsto d(x,A)$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Define $f:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$ by
$$f(x)=d(x,B)-d(x,A).$$

Show that $f$ is continuous and finish the question.

Comment: I am trying to do it without using continuity.

Comment: @user137957 You will use something equivalent to continuity anyways. You'll eventually need to find that $\epsilon$ such that the ball $B_\epsilon(x) \subset M$ where $M$ is your set. This is just like finding the $\delta$ in the $\epsilon$-$\delta$-definition of continuity.